# find command to rename each file and dir. max depth 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, command

I need find command to rename each file and dir. in my current dir.
example: 
I have files and directory:

```
abc.txt 
abcd.pdf
xyx.csv
XYS
XYZ

I want to rename it 
abc.txt -> old_abc.txt
XYZ -> old_XYZ
```

I am using something like

```
find . ! -name dbg.txt -exec rename * old_ '{}' \;
```

How i can pass each file and dir as a argument to find command.

Note: I want to avoid rename of dbg.txt file
Please help here!!

Comment: So what's the problem here? Rename files first: `-type f`, then directories: `-type d`. You can set depth with the option `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Maybe : `for fname in *; do if [[ $fname != "dbg.txt" ]]; then mv "$fname" "old_$fname";fi;done`

Comment: Here's a thought - `mv $dir old_$dir; mkdir $dir; mv old_$dir/dbg.txt $dir/;`Doesn't rename everything *in* the directory, but moves the whole thing out of the way and makes a new clean one with the one file you wanted to keep. No?

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl `rename` utility then you can use:

```
find . -type f -not -name 'dbg.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} rename -n 's~^(.+/)(.+)~$1old_$2~' '{}'
```

{lease note that `-n` is for dry run. Once you verify output of this command, remove `-n` option to rename all files.

If you don't have `rename` utility then use:

```
find . -type f -not -name 'dbg.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 -p -I {} bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}/old_${1##*/}"' - '{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*.*"|xargs sed -i 's/old_name/new_name/g'
```

However this will rename all the old names in all subdirectories and files.